# HTML5 video : Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a simple HTML 5 video block where a user can play the next video or the previous video by pressing the provided prev and next buttons.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div id="video-container">
  <h1 class="movie-title">Movie title</h1>
  <video class="videoplayer" id="video-player_transformed" playsinline autoplay muted="muted"></video>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  /**
   * Ajax response data will be stored in this local variable
   * @var    {Array}
   */
  var myData = [];

  /**
   * jQuery video element
   * @var    {Object}
   */
  var $player = $("video#videoplayer");

  /**
   * jQuery movie title element
   * @var    {Object}
   */
  var $title = $(".movie-title");

  /**
   * jQuery previous button element
   * @var    {Object}
   */
  var $prev = $(".prev");

  /**
   * jQuery next button element
   * @var    {Object}
   */
  var $next = $(".next");

  /**
   * Custom jQuery function to add sources to a media element
   * @param    {Array|String}    sources
   */
  $.fn.setSource = function(sources) {
    // Get the media tag (video/audio)
    var tag = this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase();

    // Clear any existing sources
    this.empty();

    // Check if sources paramater is an array
    if (Array.isArray(sources)) {
      // Loop through each source
      for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
        var src = sources[i];
        var type = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/.exec(src); // Get file extention (.mp4, .ogv, .webm etc)

        if (type[0]) {
          type = type[0].replace(".", "");
        }
        // Create and append a source tag
        this.append(
          $("<source>", {
            src: src,
            type: tag + "/" + type
          })
        );
      }
    } else {
      this.attr("src", sources);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Reusable function to update player element
   * @param    {Object}    data    Expects an object with `link` and `title` attributes
   */
  function updatePlayer(data) {
    $player.setSource(data.link); // Set the video source
    $title.text(data.title); // Add the title
  }

  // Disable actions because we have no data
  $prev.prop("disabled", true);
  $next.prop("disabled", true);

  // Send request to server to recieve data
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/videoexplainer/data/video.json,"
  })
    .then(function(data) {
      myData = data; // replace `myData` with the ajax response data

      // Check if we have data
      if (myData && myData.length) {
        // Re-enable actions because we have data
        $prev.prop("disabled", false);
        $next.prop("disabled", false);

        updatePlayer(data); // Set the video source (see functions above)
        $player.get(0).play(); // Play the html5 video*
        // *Most browsers will not allow playing without any user interaction
      }
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      // Request failed, inform user
      alert(
        "There was an error downloading videos, please refresh and try again."
      );
      console.warn(error);
    });

  // On click set video element to PREVIOUS video in myData
  $prev.on("click", function() {
    // Check if we have data before attempting to access it
    if (myData && myData.length) {
      updatePlayer(myData[i === 0 ? myData.length - 1 : --i]);
      $player.get(0).play();
    }

    // Prevent default click action
    return false;
  });

  // On click set video element to NEXT video in myData
  $next.on("click", function() {
    // Check if we have data before attempting to access it
    if (myData && myData.length) {
      updatePlayer(myData[i === myData.length - 1 ? 0 : ++i]);
      $player.get(0).play();
    }

    // Prevent default click action
    return false;
  });
})(jQuery || window.jQuery);
```

When I run my app, unfortunately I get the following two errors:

- As an alert, I receive the following warning:

`There was an error downloading videos, please refresh and try again.`

- In the browser console, I get the following error printed out:

  jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
      at w.fn.init.$.fn.setSource (http://localhost:8080/index_test.html:122:47)
      at updatePlayer (http://localhost:8080/index_test.html:154:25)
      at Object. (http://localhost:8080/index_test.html:176:21)
      at l (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29375)
      at c (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29677) undefined

  index_test.html:184 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
      at w.fn.init.$.fn.setSource (index_test.html:122)
      at updatePlayer (index_test.html:154)
      at Object. (index_test.html:176)
      at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
      at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I was thinking you were asking for the (nonexistent) tagName property of a jQuery object with these two lines: `$.fn.setSource = function(sources) { var tag = this.prop('tagName').toLowerCase();`, but I don't use jQuery much so that's just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line: `var $player = $('video#videoplayer');`

Needs to be changed to: `var $player = $('video.videoplayer');`

How do I know this?

1. I wrote the original code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55670566/3804924 (typo was my fault)
2. `$.ajax()` will fail if there is a code error in `.then()`. The error in this case being in the function: `.setSource()`. It's trying to get the property `tagName` of an element that doesn't exist.